# How do I hide my scrollbar on my modal window popup

Tags: javascript, jquery, scrollbar

So I'm playing around with some new web languages, and so far come up with this:

http://jsfiddle.net/lustre/j9LwghLr/

If you click on one of the pictures, a window appears with no scrollbar. Which is perfect! Exactly what I need; however, if you look closely when you click it, the items behind it shift slightly as I'm hiding the scroll bar on the body.

How do I hide it ONLY on the pop-out window? As if the pop-out window is sitting on top of the scrollbar. To stop the images behind it resizing when the window opens.

I've tried:

```
.show::-webkit-scrollbar-track {
    visibility:hidden;
}
```

However this doesn't seem to do anything... The windows open using a jQuery onclick event:

```
$(".wrapper").click(function(){
        $(this).next(".hidden").addClass("show");
        $(".wrapper").addClass("blurry");
        $("body").css("overflow","hidden");
    }); 

    $(".close").click(function(){
        $(".hidden").removeClass("show");
        $(".wrapper").removeClass("blurry");
        $("body").css("overflow","auto");
    });
```

Apologies if something doesn't make sense :) 
( To cose the pop-up window click the little green box... x3 )

jsFiddle link for you to have a play with: http://jsfiddle.net/lustre/j9LwghLr/ Again, green button closes the pop-up.

Comment: I think removing this line will help
`$("body").css("overflow","hidden");
$("body").css("overflow","auto");`

Else you need to provide us with a fiddle.

Comment: If I remove that, the pop-up has the scrollbar as well... which is what I want to avoid... Will try and set-up a jsFiddle though.

Comment: Did you try this?. Put a style on your wrapper element with overflow as hidden.

Comment: I did but it didn't work :( I've updated the question above with a jsFiddle. Also increased the width of the scrollbar to make it more obvious.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try the following solution:

```
var widht = $('body').width();
$('body').css('overflow', 'hidden')
var scrollWidth = $('body').width() - width;

$('body').css('margin-right', scrollWidth + 'px')
```

check the following fiddle

http://jsfiddle.net/j9LwghLr/4/

Answer (score 0):

```
You can calculate the width of the scrollbar by calling $('body').width() method before and after hiding the scrollbar.

Then apply right margin of the body with the scrollbar width;

Try,

var curBodyWidth = $('body').width();
$('body').css('overflow', 'hidden')
var scrollWidth = $('body').width() - curBodyWidth;

$('body').css('margin-right', scrollWidth + 'px')
```

Comment: Certainly the best solution so far!

Answer (score 0):

Replace line 1 with line 2 in your code and make sure that your timeout is in sync with the transition time which is right now 0.5s.

```
1)$("body").css("overflow","hidden");
2)setTimeout(function(){$("body").css("overflow","hidden");}, 500);
```

Comment: The problem with this solution is that it doesn't work exactly in sync with the css animation. So it's still not smooth.

Answer (score -1):

Just change `auto` to `hidden` on line 5733 in bootstrap.css (bs3.3)

```
.modal-open .modal {
  overflow-x: hidden;
  overflow-y: hidden;/*hidden to hide browser scrollbar*/
}
```